# File path from Camera Intent

Tags: android, file, path

I'm trying to get the file path of pictures that I took with Camera Intent as a String, but the String filePath is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {     
         case R.id.btnImageCapture:
            Intent openCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               startActivityForResult(openCamera, OPEN_CAMERA); 
                 break;
           }
        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         switch(requestCode){
         case OPEN_CAMERA:
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                 Uri captureImage = data.getData();
                 String filePath = captureImage.getPath();
                 break;
              } 
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get the image that was taken with the camera.

I create the file before and when the image gets saved then it gets saved to my file..

```
File externalFile = new File("Whatever you want the path to be...");
Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
Intent launchcameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
launchcameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(launchcameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Then when the result is received.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                  Bitmap photo = BitmapUtils.decodeFileForDisplay(new File("Whatever your file's path is");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think its not working for you? CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST is an id for the intent and can be defined like so `private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 123;`. The BitmapUtils.decode... line is a custom method. Use BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Comment: Yes, but it's not working for me. I don't even get an error message or something. It's just doing nothing. I also tried using WRITE_PERMISSIONS for the SDCARD, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

try the following passing your *captureImage* Uri as parameter:

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] projx = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, projx, null, null, null);
         int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

**EDIT:**

that is a common bug that getData() returns null on some devices. You need to use a pre-inserted Uri to prevent that. Example:

```
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 preinsertedUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new ContentValues());

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Getting the result:

```
         @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:

        if (resultCode != 0 && data != null) {

            Uri imageUri = preinsertedUri;
            }
              break; 
                 }
```

Comment: This crashes the app. java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {my.test.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: did u call this method after the line Uri captureImage = data.getData(); ?  Have you cheched the captureImage Uri for being null?

Comment: Yes i called the method after Uri captureImage, but now I found out that Uri is null. What can be the mistake?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check that and tell me if the Uri is still null. Don't forget to declare the preinsertedUri as a class field

Comment: Uri isn't null anymore and i get the path to the picture. Perfect! Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: you're welcome. I wasted many hours a couple months ago trying to figure out the reason for that Uri being null on certain devices only, so I recommend you to save your project for future purposes to be aware of the issue

Comment: That's a good advice for sure. I now found out another little problem. The pictures that i take with the camera intent have a size of 0.00B. I already set WRITE/READ permissions for the SDCARD and also set permission for the Camera. It seems something else is going wrong there. Do you know this problem, too?

Comment: It seems to me the code creates a file, but doesn't write any data into the file. There must still be a glitch in the code.

Comment: yes I had this issue but unfortunately I didn't come to a solution since I got another project to work on. One thing I can tell you: I was able to create a bitmap from the path and display it in an ImageView